# Socket.io issue only on mobile devices

Tags: node.js, socket.io, centos

i don understand, my socket.io works fine on desktop but on mobile it wont load socket.io.js and wont to connect do socket load socket.io.js from other url.

```
      Try it yourself - url is: http://46.252.202.193:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

on mobile it says - Internal error, request could not be serviced at this time.

when i put other socket.io.js and trys to connect socket and polling then it is allow access origin error.

On desktop works fine!

Comment: May be your mobile device browser doesn't support web-sockets

Comment: Technically socket.io should support everything! That was the plan.

Comment: Can you please provide more information?

Comment: Can somebody try link for socket.io from different mobile device?

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: Are you saying mobile can't access the URL http://46.252.202.193:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js -- the socket.io-client library itself? Looks fine to me http://mobiletest.me/samsung_galaxy_y_emulator/#u=http://46.252.202.193:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: From my samsung galaxy s4 and s5 it can load only on wifi. When it is on GSM it reports server internal error. Same with cpanel and whm. Also happening on iphone.

Comment: Sounds more a Network issue than Node/Socket issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using 3G/4G on mobile, socket.io doesn't work because 3G/4G uses "transparent" proxies.

Try the app with Wifi connected.

Comment: But there is a thing. If i use 3g on mobile socket dont work - checked on http://websocketstest.com/ , but if i make hotsopt with that 3g network and go to internet ovel laptop, scokets are working? What is solution there?

Comment: mobile + 3g - dont work (also cPanel and WHM dont work)
mobile + wifi - works
pc + same 3g from mobile - works
pc + wifi - works

Comment: Websocket in mobile browser with 3G enabled won't work because transparent proxies doesn't support WebSockets. Fore more about this topic check [link](http://blog.hekkers.net/2012/12/09/websockets-and-mobile-network-operators/)

Answer (score 0):

To add more information based on mariomako's [link](http://blog.hekkers.net/2012/12/09/websockets-and-mobile-network-operators/) in another answer -- if you're using Port 80 to make your socket requests, then changing to another port (such as 443) should help get sockets working without needing a Wifi connection.

Comment: Problem is not only in the operator. I tested websocket with native android app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.ing.websocket) and it worked on 3G, but didn't work in browser